# have lost grub been overwitten by w7 recovery

Tags: grub2

accidently I chose recovery of windows in my grub menu and it promptly overwote
now I dont have any boot at all.
I have tried various methods with no success for example
as below but when I get to sudo chroot /mnt it says unable to resolve host ubuntu.

### running 11.10 x64

You'll need to install GRUB manually. To do that you'll have to boot up using a live CD then do the following:

- Setup a chroot environment.
- open a terminal and mount the root partition to /mnt

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdXy /mnt
  ```
- sdXy being the root partition of your installed ubuntu, e.g.
  /dev/sda5. you can find that out using

  ```
     sudo fdisk -l
  ```
- next, mount some virtual devices

  ```
   sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
   sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
   sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
  ```
- chroot into the installed system

  ```
  sudo chroot /mnt
  ```
- finally, (re)install GRUB

  ```
  grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
  ```
- sdX is the internal hard drive, probably /dev/sda and while we're at it, we may as well update it, too.

  ```
  update-grub
  ```
- if there were no errors during the installation, you can type "exit"
  to leave chroot nd then simply reboot the computer. you should then
  be able to boot both windows and linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using RescaTux.  It is a live CD that will detect your operating systems and then install grub accordingly.

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/

Comment: Dean I only have a blank screen with no boot or grub menu o w7 boot. can I use what you suggested by boting pc from cd?

Comment: @Antony yes, u can. Rescatux works well.

Comment: I downloaded it but would you believe that when I took the 11.10 cd out to replace it with rescatux ubuntu booted.all ok on its own????

Comment: Anyone know of an explanation seeing how far I got with grub?

Comment: @Antony, that is amazing.  I have no explanation for that.  But it looks like it's your lucky day!  You should keep that Rescatux CD around for a rainy day.  I think you can check this question as answered to close the question.

Comment: I am certainly keeping the cd at hand.. and try to remember what I did (even if I dont know why) Maybe even though the grub intsllaer gave error it di do something? Menatime warning dont hit windows recovery loader (last option in grub) as you risk overwriting grub..cheers